# Forcing mail to a username to go through SMTP rather than local mailer

Tags: ldap, sendmail

I've got two nodes, connected via a network.  One runs an LDAP server, which both nodes use for authentication.  One is shostakovich, the other is rachmaninoff.  Each user is allowed to log in to only a single node--we'll say bob is on rachmaninoff, and jim is on shostakovich.

Right now, I've got sendmail configured so that incoming mail addressed to a full address (e.g. bob@host.tld) goes to shostakovich and is checked against ldap to decide which node it is ultimately routed to.  This works fine.

However, the problem is with local mail.  If I'm on shostakovich, and I want to be able to send mail to bob, I can do bob@host.tld and everything works fine.  However, if I send mail just to bob, because it is a local address it's not checked against LDAP and is delivered to bob on shostakovich (which checks out as a valid user because nsswitch verifies users against ldap).

How can I get even mail that appears to be going to a local user, to go through SMTP and be checked against my LDAP database for routing decisions?

Comment: Not that it's an answer, but why not ensure that the mail is generated to a fully-qualified email address?  It seems that someone's been lazy in the generation of email, and that you're now trying to get sendmail to clear it up.  Fixing the underlying problem might be better.  (It's still a well-written and interesting question, though; +1 from me.)

Comment: Check you sendmail log files. Your MTA on 127.0.0.1:25 does not get email addressed to domainless `bob`, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Create alias for `bob` on `shostakovich`.

/etc/mail/aliases file entry required:

```
bob:  bob@host.tld
```

P.S. aliases file requires recompilation using `newaliases` command.